# Is there a term for "toilet" that isn't a euphemism?

Tags: synonyms

By "toilet" I'm speaking of the thing upon which someone does their "business" -- commode, throne, W.C., etc.  Every synonym I can find is somehow a euphemism (as is "toilet", of course).  And the same appears to be true (with the possible exception of "shithouse") for "toilet" when used to mean "rest room".

Are there any specific terms which are not simply euphemisms (and didn't start as euphemisms) but specifically refer to the appliance or room?

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul That just means a small room with a water supply!

Comment: You've posted the non-euphemism yourself: shithouse.

Comment: @WeatherVane - I noted that as a possible exception.

Comment: I'm not sure that any exists. *Toilet* is [itself a euphemism](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/toilet#Etymology), deriving from a diminutive form of a French word for _cloth_, adopted for such use due to the association with shaving. Meanwhile, the plumbing fixture represented by this term is an adaptation of a chamber pot, which also has no particular non-euphemistic representation in language.

Comment: I think it'd be good for the question to specify what is intended by 'euphemism', and for answers to be aware of dysphemisms, minced taboo words, and the euphemism treadmill. Also, since the distinction came up in a comment, whether it is important that the thing being named (the appliance) is where one urinates, defecates or is it OK if both occur. Also whether it is American or British or other English you're looking for.

Comment: Given that it is possible that some people do not perceive *toilet* as much of a euphemism any more, it might be better to formulate the question as: is there any word for this entity that did not start out as a euphemism? Also, as the question itself lists one dysphemism for it, what is really being asked is: is there any word for it that started out as neither a euphemism nor a dysphemism?

Comment: https://www.lexico.com/definition/comfort_room; where toilet's synonym is 'comfort room'. Indian Prime Minister Mr. Modi called it Izzat Ghat = home of dignity.

Answer (score 2):

Lavatory and latrine are synonyms of toilet which aren't euphemisms.

Comment: c. 1300, laterin "a privy," probably from Latin latrina, latrinum, a contraction of lavatrina "washbasin, washroom," from lavatus, past participle of lavare "to wash"

Comment: Latrine yes, lavatory no - that's strictly a wash room, so it's like the 'bathroom' euphemism.

Comment: Yes, but compared to 'commode', and 'throne', it isn't much of a euphemism.

Comment: A *latrine* is specifically a communal toilet, especially one that is not a plumbing fixture. It is not appropriate when referring to a residential setting.

Comment: If "toilet" and "w.c." are euphemisms,  or originated as euphemisms, then lavatory is also.

Comment: Latrine & lavatory both come from Latin words for 'bathe' or 'wash', and as such remain euphemisms.

Answer (score 1):

- Piss pot
- The shitter
- The can
- The pot
- The bog
- Urinal
- Pissoir

Comment: In Australia, a dunny. Also a crapper, named after the inventor of the flush toilet. In England, a loo.

Comment: @Peter [**Thomas Crapper**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Crapper) was an English sanitary engineer, so here too. We have a variety of terms for the "bog".

Comment: Of course, "urinal" and "pissoir" do not refer to the appliance you sit on.

Comment: In the British Navy: the "head".

Comment: @WeatherVane US Navy also. It refers to the time of sailing ships when the toilet was located at the front of a ship.

Comment: @Cascabel so not past the capn's window!

Comment: @WeatherVane so as not to blow the excrement back where it came from!

Comment: Although *pissoir* is not a euphemism in the language of its origin, I wonder whether it might not be at least a mild euphemism in English. Borrowing words from other languages is a familiar technique of creating euphemisms.

Comment: @jsw29, I think the meaning is pretty obvious even if you don't know French.

Comment: Crap is not from Thomas Crapper, it's much older and probably from chaff, waste https://www.etymonline.com/word/crap

Comment: The first two here seem to get to the point of it. You have to make a noun out of a word that means urinate or defecate. Which is why we have the euphemisms, because it can be an unpleasant action to think about.

Answer (score 0):

Because of its Latin origins, I would suggest latrine (n.) from etymon online:

> c. 1300, laterin "a privy," probably from Latin latrina, latrinum, a contraction of lavatrina "washbasin, washroom," from lavatus, past participle of lavare "to wash" (from PIE root *leue- "to wash") + -trina, suffix denoting "workplace." The word's reappearance in 1640s probably is a re-borrowing from French. In modern use, especially of a public privy of a camp, barracks, college, hospital, etc.

The idea of washing is accurate, there is simply no note of what part of your body - as a Roman - you will be washing with your sponge on a stick dipped in vinegar, and this is fair enough - nouns often do not suggest the **whole** idea.

Added to this, there was usually some water around to cleanse any mess, so it would not be unreasonable to have “wash” in some form as a general function to be performed within the room – not simply the anus.

The other point is philosophical – whichever current term is the earliest recorded or has the longest pedigree should be accepted as the non-euphemistic one. I suggest that it is not possible to have a word that is only expressed by euphemisms, as a euphemism has to relate to something.

Comment: Still, it means wash.

Comment: @JanKyuPeblik - well it certainly **used to** refer to wash - meanings change over time

Answer (score -1):

‘Loo’ derives from ‘l’eau’ meaning water. Americans, to be polite, say ‘bathroom’. I’d hate to bathe in that! The medieval garderobe only refers to the custom of putting the best clothes in that room set aside for human voiding as it (supposedly) deterred moths, thus guarding ones robes. ‘As if mothballs aren’t stinky enough!). Elizabethans had the ‘room of easement’. I wonder if that is what Ms Rowling had in mind when inventing the room of requirement in Harry Potter novels. As for me, no ‘visiting my auntie’ or coy silliness. I go pee!

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question.